# ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z' in pandas 0.23.4 and not 0.24.2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I was getting this error in a Python 3 program  I'm developing. A simplified version of what caused the error is

```py
import pandas as pd

fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'
date_string = '2019-05-25T12:34:56.000+0000'
print(pd.to_datetime(arg = date_string, format = fmt))
```

The error is

`ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'`

Eventually I realized I was using the wrong conda environment, one which runs pandas 0.23.4 rather than 0.24.2, so I'm curious as to why the error occurs in the former but not the latter.

Comment: Shouldn't that be capital `Z`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see the error in the older 0.23 version of pandas because `%Z` and `%z` directives were not yet implemented.

According to [What’s New in 0.24.0 (January 25, 2019)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html):

> [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) now supports the `%Z` and `%z` directive when passed into format.

And here is related issue on GitHub: [ENH: bad directive in to_datetime format - this uses std. strptime zone offset #13486](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13486)